# TCPDF SetMargins method

Tags: tcpdf

I'm working to get exact positioning in tcpdf.  I'm trying to use SetMargins() in multiple places, but I must be misunderstanding the usage of this method.
It doesn't seem to be working as I expect.

```
$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 12);
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetMargins(10, 10, 10, true); // set the margins 

$html = 'Here is some text';

$pdf->writeHTMLCell(0, 0, '', '', $html, 'LRTB', 1, 0, true, 'L', true); 

$pdf->SetMargins(0, 10, 0, true); // put space of 10 on top 

$pdf->writeHTMLCell(0, 0, '', '', $html, 'LRTB', 1, 0, true, 'C', true);
$pdf->writeHTMLCell(0, 0, '', '', $html, 'LRTB', 1, 0, true, 'R', true);      

$pdf->Output('example_002.pdf', 'I');
```

I'm definitely getting an output, but I'm expecting the first and second writeHTMLCell() to have the space reset between them.

http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/classTCPDF.html#ab3bbdb7c85ea08d175fd559be6132ba0

The documentation says the second parameter is for top margin.

In short, I want to mess with margins for each line, if necessary. But I may be using the wrong method for this.
My example above seems to be ignoring that parameter entirely. But it doesn't seem to have a problem with the left and right parameters.

Answer (score 11):

The TCPDF `SetMargins` method is:

```
SetMargins($left,$top,$right = -1,$keepmargins = false)
```

So you can use it before `AddPage();` method like below:

```
$pdf->SetMargins(10, 20, 10, true);
$pdf->AddPage();
//your HTML code here ...
```

`$keepmargins(boolean)` if true overwrites the default page margins.

Answer (score 4):

Use SetY() instead. This will set the cursor position from the top of the page

Comment: please explain where to use this function, what parameters does it accept, do you have a link to an example? or a link to it's documentation?

Comment: This is the right answer!   Thanks for this.  This is the code I used to set a top margin of zero: `$pdf->SetY(0, true, true);`

Answer (score 2):

You can use simply:

```
$pdf->Ln()
$pdf->Ln(15.5)
```

to add vertical space between two rows.

Normally you set margins only once - when initiating the PDF document.
Dont use margins to control horizontal/vertical coords.